# Sync iPod Classic on Asus Tablet

Tags: asus-transformer-infinity

I have a lot of music on both my iPod Classic (pre-iOS type), and my Asus Transformer tablet. Is it possible to sync the two for music and pictures? Or am I forced to use a computer?

The tablet is rooted, and the iPod does have Disk Usage enabled. All the music files show up as just 4-letter folders and filenames though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar setup with iPod Classic (160 GB) and Asus Transformer TF300T. I have yet to find a direct method to connect iPod to the tablet and sync via an app. As of now, the only way is via a computer.

If you want to go the PC way, you can use [iSyncr for PC](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrtstudio.iSyncr) and sync playlists. iSyncr also has an app for Mac. 
However, I am not sure of pictures being synced via iSyncr.

Another option is to export all the music via programs like [Floola](http://www.floola.com/home/) to your computer and later transfer to the tablet.

Comment: I'm mostly wanting to send data to the iPod

Comment: I am afraid the data sent to iPod from Transformer will not be showing up in iPod's song list. This is because, iPod only recognises the files listed in iTunesDB file under iPod_Control folder. In order to manage music/pictures in iPod you need to connect it to a computer.

Comment: I realize just copying to it wouldn't work, but I was hoping an app would allow me to transfer

Comment: As of now no app can do it in Android.